# Is there a way to let the user choose the columns in a dax groupby formula in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with spending information per week, gender and age group.

```
    Sample Table = {
    (1,"Man","0-10",9),
    (1,"Woman","0-10",10),
    (1,"Man","10-30",8),
    (1,"Woman","10-30",2),
    (1,"Man","30-60",4),
    (1,"Woman","30-60",6),
    (1,"Man","60+",9),
    (1,"Woman","60+",8),
    (2,"Man","0-10",6),
    (2,"Woman","0-10",4),
    (2,"Man","10-30",8),
    (2,"Woman","10-30",8),
    (2,"Man","30-60",7),
    (2,"Woman","30-60",10),
    (2,"Man","60+",3),
    (2,"Woman","60+",8),
    (3,"Man","0-10",3),
    (3,"Woman","0-10",10),
    (3,"Man","10-30",3),
    (3,"Woman","10-30",10),
    (3,"Man","30-60",1),
    (3,"Woman","30-60",9),
    (3,"Man","60+",8),
    (3,"Woman","60+",5)
    }
```

Using this table, I can calculate the amount of spending per group. A 'group' can be defined in different ways: 'Men' (only gender) or 'Men in age group <60' (gender + age group) or 'Men in age group <60 in week 25' (gender + age group + weeknumber) etc. To calculate the amount spent per group (in this case, groupby per gender+weeknumber), I make a new table use the following dax codes:

```
grouped spending = 

VAR spending = 
    GROUPBY('Sample Table', 
    'Sample Table'[Weeknumber],
    'Sample Table'[Gender], 
    "sum_spent_group", 
    SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), 'Sample Table'[spent]))

RETURN
    spending
```

And add a column to this table to calculate the part spent by the chosen group over the total amount spent:

```
spending part = 

DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM('grouped spending'[sum_spent_group]),
                    ALLEXCEPT('grouped spending','grouped spending'[group])),
                    SUM('grouped spending'[sum_spent_group])
                     )
```

Now I can show the spending percentage of a group over the total amount of spending:

[image]

Is there a way I can let the user choose (using buttons/bookmarks/etc..?) choose which columns should be in the groupby? In other words; is it possible to make this code more general, and let the user specify the group combination? As well as for the numerator as denomerator.

I realize one solution is to make columns for all group combinations, but in my real data, I have many more categories, so that will take a lot of space (and a lot of work..).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In first place, way you use GROUPBY + SUMX? Where you use this measures? In table? Card visualization? Probably you can use calculate(SUM(data[spent])), and allowed user to select some filters and use slicers; Share with your sample data and desired result.

Comment: @msta42a: I edited my question, hopefully it is more clear this way! I know about the use of filters and slicers, however, I can only use them to choose rows. Here I want to use a different selection of columns..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't actually need to create a separate table for each group.

1. Create a measure to calculate sum of spent that will be influenced by slicers (your group). Something like `spent_calc = SUM('Sample Table'[spent])`
2. Create a measure to calculate total spent regardless of slicers selected `CALCULATE(SUM('Sample Table'[spent]),ALL('Sample Table'))`
3. Create measure that calculates percentage of total spent `%_spent_by_selected_group = DIVIDE([spent_calc],[total_spent])`
4. Create slicers and put percentage measure into a desired visual, e.g. [image: example of report]

Now a user can create any combination of attributes and see the percentage of the total spent. The caveat is of course you will have to have a lot of slicers if you have a lot of categories, so it might not be the most elegant solution. Probably the easiest one though.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a better approach than making new tables indeed. However, the one thing I'm still struggling with, is that I also want the denominator to be chosen by the user. For example, %spent of all 60+ men over all men (and not all people).

Comment: I fixed it for my case: Changing CALCULATE(SUM('Sample Table'[spent]),ALL('Sample Table')) to CALCULATE(SUM('Sample Table'[spent]),ALL('Sample Table'[Gender])). Because in the dominator, I want the same categorization als de numerator, except for the gender. So thank you @Michael, you were really helpful!